# How can I create an RSS feed for a specific question?

Tags: support, questions, feed

I used to create an RSS feed for question by using a link:

> https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/[question_id]

It is not the correct URL. But I know it's possible. I do not remember the exact way to do it. I could not find the procedure to do it. So I am asking it here.

Comment: No-repro. This is the URL where the [question feed] link leads to, and it returns me an application/atom+xml just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* the correct link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/328187
The RSS URL is shown under the *Hot Network Questions* widget on each Q&A page:

> [image: feed link location]

Comment: It worked like a charm. @Glorfindel